# What are some alternative words/phrases for Wargame/Wargaming?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

I am pursuing a doctoral research and because of lack of data in my specific domain, I want to use war-gaming as a methodology. However my advisor won't be very comfortable with the military connotations of the word "Wargame". "Simulation" is too computer-ish and doesn't wholly capture what I want to do.

What are my other options?

Example sentence: Because of lack of data, the methodology used in this study was to *wargame* crises scenarios along with......

Comment: What aspect of "wargaming" are you using in your research?

Comment: You may be able to use “adversarial” or “competitive” with simulation or trial. It’s difficult to say without an example sentence. You may want to check out the tag “single-word-request” and read the guidance in the tag description.

Comment: If your topic is "cyber" + anything, please note that *cyberwarfare* has a lot of military connotations. If your topic involves game theory, you could use *zero-sum game* .

Comment: Not all games are zero-sum. Game theory is a field all its own, at least in some eras. See “prisoner’s dilemma”. Remember you adviser has access to the internet too.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, since you mentioned simulation was "too computer-ish", is [role-playing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing#Research_method).

Another is to drop "war" and call it gaming.  As a noun and intransitive verb, I think this meets the criteria.  I would not use it as a transitive verb, as this generally means using knowledge of a system to take advantage of a person or situation.

Answer (score 0):

*Simulation* predates computers by many years, the meaning you are after started in the 1950s, when computers couldn't really do this work.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simulation)

> *simulation*
> noun [ C/U ]
> a model of a real activity, created for training purposes or to solve a problem: